# ¿Cómo hacer test performance en jmeter para Drupal?

Tags: rendimiento

Tengo un módulo para crear un usuario. Cuando creo la variable en **jmeter** de email y cuando simulo 100 usuarios, me va a dar problema por que el usuario ya va estar creado en la primera simulación. ¿Cómo haría para simular la creación de dichos usuarios?

Tengo un wizard un menu,ahi son un conjunto de opciones que cada uno hace lo suyo, pero ¿cómo haría para meter eso en el jmeter y manejar las variables? es la misma url, pero yo puedo navegar entre las opciones y agregar cosas dentro de ellas y demás

Comment: Osea sólo un usuario puedes crear? No es muy explícito tú pregunta formulada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cargar un archivo con los nombres de los usuarios a crear
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]